Posting non-questions on Stack Overflow
I was just wondering if there was any way to post things like code to Stack Overflow.
I was thinking of just posting something as a way of preemptively answering questions. I know that some people just look for answers on this site, but if they don't find it they just leave without asking questions.

No, you can't post a non-question post on SO. It is a question and answer site, which means that there must first be a question asked before it can be answered.
You can, however, post a question yourself and then answer it, but note that both the question and answer are required to meet the same quality standards as any other on SO. See Can I answer my own question? for more details. Also note that questions about SO itself belong here on Meta, not the main site.

The only exception is Articles within Collectives.
